# Accepted answer is missing

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I sometimes see questions with a clear answer addressing the question and upvoted by other users, but not marked as the **accepted answer** (neither the rest of answers), so the question remains unanswered.

This tends to happen when new users raise questions and do not mark the accepted answer, probably because they still don't know the overall methodology within Stack Exchange.

I believe it is not a good practise to ask the question creator via comments to mark the best answer as accepted (which seems to be the only way to get in touch with users).

Therefore, is there a way to cleanse the unanswered questions and choose the accepted answer -*if applicable*- by the community in case they are effectively addressing the question? Perhaps there could be a clear criteria such as a minimum number of upvotes in the answer, consensus by moderators, N months after the question was created without accepted answer, etc.

Comment: I feel that the OP is sometimes obligated to accept an answer, but the rules indicate otherwise unfortunately. That being said, I think maybe gold badge users should decide after minimum number of upvotes, and N months after the question was created.

Comment: No, because acceptance *means* "the asker found this answer to be the most useful". There's no possible way that anyone else ever could or should be able to determine what the asker thinks.